# Reverse substring for double extension files

Tags: javascript

How can i add reverse substring for "**test.csv.txt**" this type of files using javascript?

Comment: WWHHHUUUAAAATTTT !!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Billy's comment summed up your question quite nicely if I'm honest, but I'll have a go.

By reverse substring, do you mean starting from the start, up to your index?

```
str.substr(0, length);
```

Maybe you want to remove it from the last `.`?

```
var str = "test.csv.txt";
str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf('.')); // "test.csv"
```

"for this type of files"? Perhaps you only want to do this when there are two `.`s?

```
if(str.split(/\./g).length > 2) //only executes if there are 2 or more dots
  str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```